# How to make the same style for all objects in a uiview in Xcode 6.1 iOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, stylesheet

I am new to iOS programming. I'd like to know, is there any way to do things like what CSS does in HTML pages (describing look and formatting of objects) in xcode6.1?
I looked at UIAppearance and this page:
http://akosma.com/2010/06/03/objective-c-categories-as-stylesheets/
but I don't know which method is better or there may be better ways

Comment: You can use pixate framework and with css you can manage this. https://github.com/Pixate/Xamarin-PixateFreestyle

Comment: does this framework work on xcode too?

Comment: Yes I have used in one of my project. You can refer the link which I have shared. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to PixateFreestyle and the limited set of properties exposed to CSS, you could also try using a library I create called Stylish.

This allows you to create styles and stylesheet in code, or in an external JSON file, and apply them at runtime. Additionally, unlike other libraries, Stylish lets you assign styles to views using the IB inspector and renders the live in the Storyboard, without needing to compile the app first:

https://github.com/daniel-hall/Stylish